# Webview sending incorrect Origin header

Tags: android, cordova, webview, android-webview, cors

Recently I have been debugging some CORS related issue with my Phonegap application with Tomcat server as back-end.

I figured out that Client (WebView) is sending incorrect value in Origin Header : . The value is "file:\" .

To rule out Phonegap , I created a Android Application from scratch and tried the same. The results were similar. See below the header

```
Request URL:http://medistreet.in/auth2
Request Method:POST
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Request Headers
POST http://medistreet.in/auth2 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
**Origin: file://**
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; XT1033 Build/KXB20.25-1.31) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

And Android code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
        WebSettings settings=webView.getSettings();
        settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    }

}
```

Any idea??

Comment: Anybody from Android team who can help on this??

Answer (score 0):

When sending the Origin header the KitKat WebView will send the host part of the URL. The concept of host doesn't really apply to the file:// scheme which is why you're getting a bogus value.

I imagine it was different for the pre-KK WebView which used KURL instead of GURL for URL processing. GURL is generally more strict (and more secure) than KURL, which is the cause for some incompatibility between the two WebView versions.

The `loadUrl` method takes extra headers but the KK WebView doesn't let you override the Origin header using that API.

To work around this you could try using `loadDataWithBaseURL` with medistreet.in as the base URL or overriding `WebViewClient.shouldOverrideUrlLoading` to make it seem like your local resources are coming from the server.